# Store a printed result in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I want to obtain all URL's from a web, and storage the result as a variable. So far, I've found the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.sport.es/") # Insert your URL to extract
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read());

for link in bsObj.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The result is just what I want, but I need to storage it as a variable to build a dataframe. How can I do it?

Thanks to all.

Best regards,

Comment: Why do you need to store the urls in a pandas data frame?

Comment: Because I need to work with different variables (not only the url) stored in columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, construct a list of links. You can append to an empty list within your `for` loop:

```
list_of_links = []

for link in bsObj.find_all('a'):
    list_of_links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Or, more succinctly, you can use a list comprehension:

```
list_of_links = [link.get('href') for link in bsObj.find_all('a')]
```

Then you can feed the list to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor via a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'links': list_of_links})
```